# How to handle the situation when the literals are equal to the matches

Tags: c#, regex

I need a regex or C# code that will match this string (retrieve all the xxx values):

```
...value xxx value value xxx value xxx...
```

Where x is a non specified number of chars or symbols. I could know the length of the string. But Important , when the xxx is equal to "value" the regex or the program should not crash or fail.
The order value xxx value is well known.

Comment: Not quite understanding you; maybe you could provide a more concrete example?

Comment: Where does the word "literals" come into play here?

Comment: not possible, unless there are additional special rules concerning how 'value' appears in 'xxx' so it can be distinguished from 'value' that is the prefix to 'xxx'.

Comment: ok..I wanna do in this case a regular expression and to not match the xxx value if it contains the string "value". would be this possible ?

Answer (score 0):

```
...value (.*?) value value (.*?) value (.*?)...
```

Comment: ok. but ..if xxx is equal to "this value" I wanna to catch all the string "this value".

Comment: assuming all the other literal values are present, you will.

Answer (score 0):

It might help if you can give some examples. How about this -

```
[jaypal~]$ echo "value xxx value value xxx value xxx" | sed 's/\bvalue\b//g'
 xxx   xxx  xxx
```